# How can I do a select query with dynamic alias with mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, dynamic, alias

How do I do a dynamic alias in mysql?

I have actually this query:

```
SELECT c.user_name AS client_name, c.user_firstname AS client_firstname FROM users
```

And I would like to simplify it like this:

```
SELECT * AS ??? FROM users
```

Comment: You can't give an alias to `*` (unless there is only one column in the table).  I don't even understand what you really want to do.  The first version is the correct syntax for SQL.

Comment: I want to make an alias for all fields replacing user_ by client_ in the column name

Comment: You need to list them out separately.  You can use `information_schema.columns` to automatically generate the code, but you have to paste it in.